# Is it possible to nest a Razor section within a Razor form block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following block of Razor markup:

```
@section StoreSearch
{
    @Html.Partial("SearchPartial", Model)
}
<section id="gallery-index">
...
</section>
<nav class="pager">
    <a href="#" rel="prev" class="pager-nav" title="Previous Page">Prev</a> Page @(Model.PageIndex + 1) of @Model.PageCount <a href="#" rel ="next" class="pager-nav" title="Next Page">Next</a>
</nav>
```

I would like to surround this whole block with a form, as in

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "search-form" }))
{
    @section StoreSearch
    {
        @Html.Partial("SearchPartial", Model)
    }
    <section id="gallery-index">
        ...
}
```

Yet when I do that, the parser seems to balk at the `@section StoreSearch` part, and complains "Cannot resolve symbol StoreSearch".

Is what I'm trying to do not allowed, or am I just missing some sort of escaping method?

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens if you wrap your `@section { ... }` with a `div`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, that seems to fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug in the Razor parsing engine.  Most likely the first @ sign in a using clause is being parsed as a variable, which in your case is actually a function so it's throwing an exception.  For now the solution is to surround your section with a `div` (or any html element really).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { id = "search-form" }))
{
  <div>
    @section StoreSearch
    {
      @Html.Partial("SearchPartial", Model)
    }
    <section id="gallery-index">
    ...
    </section>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seeem to work in MVC 5. The form is not rendered at all? There is no error in the parser, however, the form is just not rendered in the resulting html.

Comment: I can't test currently.  However, I would suggest surrounding either the `@Html.Partial` with an html element (like a div) and/or the code the parial is rendering with an html element (like a div).